# How to display the created file name and contents on textview?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How to display the created file name and contents on textview? This is my code. Iam able to display the file name and its contents in NSLog but not on textview though i have given the outlet for textview. Please help me with this issue.

```
-(IBAction) open: (id) sender

{

// Create instance of UITextView
textView = [UITextView alloc];
                 initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();

// Add text
textView.text= homeDir;
NSLog(@"%@", homeDir);

textfield.text= @"output will go here..";

NSString *myFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                        pathForResource:@"Myfile"
                        ofType:@"txt"];


NSString *myFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:myFilePath
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                        error:nil];


NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFilePath: %@, Contents of file:%@",myFilePath, myFileContents];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
textView.text= s;
}
```

Comment: To show file contents, i suggest to used QLPreviewController

Comment: if outlet connected why allocing a new instance ? Remove that line and try again

Answer (score 0):

Does the textView work at all? Have you tried:
`textView.text = @"TestText"`? If the textView remains empty you need to check the outlet/ check whether the textView is added to the ViewController properly. I think this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your text view setup.

- If an outlet is connected to the text view, you do not need to create it in code (which you are doing).
- If you create it in code, you have to add it as a subview to the desired view (which you are not doing).

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the textview in your parentview; I assume you are creating runtime textview. Just add this line in your code.

```
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```